# Create a tuple list from a list using fold_left

Tags: list, ocaml, fold

How to create a tuple list from one single list, like so:
`[1; 2; 4; 6] -> [(1, 2); (4, 6)]`

I want to do it using function `List.fold_left` since I'm trying to learn that currently but don't know how... Is there a way? Or should I leave it like that?

This is a working code that doesn't use `List.fold_left`:

```
let rec create_tuple acc l = match l with
  | [] -> acc
  | x :: y :: l' -> create_tuple (acc @ [(x, y)]) l'
  | _ -> acc
```

Comment: What's your question? The code doesn't work, and you know why, so what's stopping you from fixing it?

Comment: It works for me when I do it like this. I want to do the same but with List.fold_left

Comment: “Or should I leave it like that?” What a question is that? Do what you want… There is no superior OCaml authority that will blame you for solving this problem without using `List.fold_left`… except a teacher?

Comment: Aside on your working code (you will face the same issue with `List.fold_left`): beware that your current code is very inefficient for long lists (quadratic time) because list concatenation takes a time proportional to the length of its left-hand side. The usual trick for building a list one element at a time is to prepend new elements (`(x, y) :: acc`) rather than appending them (`acc @ [ (x, y) ]`), and then, at the very end, reverse the entire accumulator.

Comment: `List.fold_left` operates on the first element in the list and an accumulator. You have no direct way of matching the first _and_ second elements in the list. The key is going to be the accumulator you use.

Comment: I should say I'm getting a bit tired by your questions that all look like student questions, don't show any (or very little) previous work and are unclear as to what is asked. I'm not usually severe on SO but you're not doing any effort to make me want to answer to you and I don't think anyone should since your questions are not really the kind of accepted questions on SO. Please think a bit on what you're asking, how you're asking it and the minimum effort we require to answer to you.

Comment: And following this comment, naturally, I'll ask for your question to be closed because it's too open and unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I agree overall, but *here* the question is clear and makes sense.

Comment: Aside from what has been stated, one of the keys to SO etiquette is to learn from answers that are provided. Students (we all are, at various levels) are welcome to ask questions. Just make sure that your questions show progression of skill. If you ask how to do X in question A, and get a good answer, you can ask question B, but if it has question X in it again, it will not be well-received.

Comment: @Maëlan The question is "How can I do it with List.fold_left or should I abandon the idea?". No work provided to start doing it with List.fold_left, just an open question with very little previous work. I like both your answers, from Chris and you, but this question for me should not have received any ;-)

Comment: @Lhooq thank you for your honest words. Although I think you're unfair with me. You don't know how much work I put into it. You see I'm completely new to SO and programming with meta languages. I'm currently attending an online class at a school and really want to learn this. I was looking for hours how to solve the issue but my code didn't make sense at all. To describe my problem better I wrote it without fold_left, so you fantastic people know what I tried to achieve. Obviously I could've pasted my completely wrong and misleading fold.left code in my question. I'll do it next time. Thanks!

Comment: @jhn.brg I'm not unfair since the only thing I have to judge your questions are... your questions ;-) A lot of them look like "student questions" asking us to do your homework without providing the minimum required effort for us to think that you even tried. From your comment, I realise I was wrong, you tried, but then show us how you tried and we will help you based on what you did. Because "Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime."

Comment: @Lhooq thank you! They may look like "student questions" but they aren't, I don't have homework. I'm eager to learn OCaml. I didn't see necessarity in pasting my code. For sure I will do so next time!

Answer (score 4):

`List.fold_left` reads elements one by one. There is no direct way to make it read elements two by two.

It really is pointless complication (great for teaching, though), but if you absolutely want to use `List.fold_left` here, your accumulator needs to somehow record the state of the traversal:

- either you have read an even number of elements so far,
- or you have read an odd number and then you have to record what was the last element you read, so that, upon reading the following one, you can pair them.

Here is a way to do it. I use an algebraic datatype to represent the state.

```ml
(* This is the type that we’ll use for the accumulator;
   the option component is the state of the traversal.
   (None, acc) means that we have read an even number of elements so far;
   (Some x, acc) means that we have read an odd number of elements so far,
   the last of which being x. *)
type 'a accumulator = 'a option * ('a * 'a) list

let folder (state, acc) x =
  match state with
  | None   -> (Some x, acc)
  | Some y -> (None, (y,x)::acc)

let create_pairs l =
  let (_, acc) = List.fold_left folder (None, []) l in
  List.rev acc
```

Also notice how I avoid the complexity bug that I outlined in a comment: I add elements in reverse order (i.e. at the *head* of the accumulating list), and at the very end I reverse that list.

Comment: Worth noting that the option type value is discarded, _but_ you might want to keep this if you needed to keep track of this if you need to know if the list actually contained an even number of elements. E.g. `let (flag, acc) = List.fold_left folder (None, []) l in match flag with None -> Some (List.rev acc) | Some _ -> None`

Answer (score 3):

@Maëlan's answer is beautiful, but what if we want to get triples rather than pairs? Is there a way we can use `List.fold_left` to handle this more generically?

```ml
let chunks n lst =
  let (_, _, acc) = List.fold_left 
    (fun (counter, chunk, lst') x ->
       if counter = n - 1 then
         (0, [], List.rev (x :: chunk) :: lst')
       else
         (counter + 1, x :: chunk, lst'))
    (0, [], [])
    lst 
  in
  List.rev acc
```

Using this, `chunks 2 [1; 2; 4; 6]` returns `[[1; 2]; [4; 6]]`. We can map this to the result you're looking for with a very simple function that takes a list with two elements and creates a tuple with two elements.

```
[1; 2; 4; 6] 
|> chunks 2  
|> List.map (fun [x; y] -> (x, y))
```

And we get:

```
[(1, 2), (4, 6)]
```

This could be used to implement a triples function.

```
let create_triples lst =
  lst
  |> chunks 3 
  |> List.map (fun [x; y; z] -> (x, y, z));;
```

And now `create_triples [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9]` returns `[(1, 2, 3); (4, 5, 6); (7, 8, 9)]`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this question(using List.fold_left) and this is the best I could come up with:

```
type 'a node = First of 'a | Second of ('a * 'a)

let ans =
  List.fold_left
    (
      fun a e ->
        match a with
        | [] -> (First e)::a
        | (First f)::tl -> Second(f, e)::tl
        | (Second n)::tl -> (First e)::(Second n)::tl
    )
    []
    [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; ]

let () =
  List.iter
    (
      fun e ->
        match e with
        | First f ->
          print_endline(string_of_int f)
        | Second (f, s) ->
          Printf.printf "(%d, %d)" f s
    )
    (List.rev ans)
```

Just to make my answer all there...

```
type 'a node = One of 'a | Two of ('a * 'a)

let ans =
  (List.map
     (
       fun e ->
         match e with
         | One _ -> failwith "Should only be Two's"
         | Two (f, s) -> (f, s)
     )
     (List.filter
        (
          fun e ->
            match e with
            | One _ -> false
            | Two _ -> true
        )
        (List.rev 
           (List.fold_left
              (
                fun a e ->
                  match a with
                  | [] -> (One e)::[]
                  | (One o)::tl -> (Two (o, e))::tl
                  | (Two t)::tl -> (One e)::(Two t)::tl
              )
              []
              (List.init 10 (fun x -> x + 1))
           )
        )
     )
  )

let () =
  List.iter
    (fun (f, s) -> Printf.printf "(%d, %d) " f s)
    ans
```

Comment: If you take `ans`, reverse it, and map it from `Second (x, y)` to `(x, y)`, you're there.